# Add a button with onclick event in infowindow

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to add a button with onclick event in the infowindow of google map api v3

```
        var cont = "<div><h4><b>Transformer</b></h4><label>Name: </label>"+this.transformerName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.transformerName.substring(1)+"<br><label>Site No: </label>"+this.siteNo+"<br><label>Substation No: </label>"+this.substationNo+"<br><label>Transformer No: </label>"+this.unitNo+"<br><button onclick='voltagemodel()'>voltagetrend</button></div>";
    console.log(cont);
    infowindow.setContent(cont);
```

but the onclick event is not firing kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
  <button onclick='voltagemodel();'>voltagetrend</button>
```

you missed **`;`**